# ffmpeg loudness doesn't return any file

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm using a shared server managed by Aruba.it
It uses

```
ffmpeg version 4.1
built with gcc 4.8.5
(GCC) 20150623
(Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
```

I need to use ffmpeg to fix the loudness of any uploaded MP3 to -12 dB LUFS -1 dB TP

I found on internet the following commands, but not any output.mp3 is generated

**PHP**

```
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i Temp.mp3 -af loudnorm=I=-12:LRA=7:tp=-2:measured_I=-30:measured_LRA=1.1:measured_tp=-11 04:measured_thresh=-40.21:offset=-0.47 -y output.mp3");
```

Where do I wrong please?

**EDIT**
Not any error is returned.

Comment: Does that command run without errors in terminal?

Comment: Not any error is returned either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by @llogan I found the solution.
It should be in 3 steps and not in only one.
The MP3 to MP3 doesn't work, on my case.
So I converted the input MP3 into wave, normalized  it, and converted back to MP3

```
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i Temp.mp3 Temp.wav");
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i Temp.wav -af loudnorm=I=-12:LRA=7:tp=-2:measured_I=-30:measured_LRA=1.1:measured_tp=-11.04:measured_thresh=-40.21:offset=-0.47 output.wav");
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i output.wav -ab 320k output.mp3");
```

this solution worked perfectly

Comment: Try `exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i Temp.mp3 -af loudnorm=I=-12:LRA=7:tp=-2:measured_I=-30:measured_LRA=1.1:measured_tp=-11 04:measured_thresh=-40.21:offset=-0.47,aresample=48000 -y output.mp3");`

Comment: @Gyan unfortunately not. I think it's something related Aruba.it. The only one way I got a result, is with the three lines I posted above

Answer (score 1):

If you run it manually, unscripted in your terminal you will get an error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for '04:measured_thresh=-40.21:offset=-0.47'
04:measured_thresh=-40.21:offset=-0.47: Invalid argument
```

There is an errant space in your command, so change `measured_tp=-11 04` to `measured_tp=-11.04`.

Comment: I cannot run into a terminal. As I said: it's a shared server from a  provider. However: removing the space putting a dot as you suggested: a file is generated. But it's 0 bytes size. The input file is 1.9MB about

Comment: @TormyVanCool Mentioning that it is a shared server does not imply that you have no shell access. I've used dozens of shared servers with shell access. Anyway, without any sort of log or error or any other additional useful information to work with we can only provide guesses and not true, turnkey answers. Your fixed command works for me in a terminal, so I believe the ffmpeg specific issue is solved.

Comment: unfortunately many things from that provider are suffering. however, the generated file is 0 bytes. I can't understand what's missing :-/

Comment: @TormyVanCool This is actually two questions in one: 1) how do I do this in ffmpeg 2) how do I implement this in PHP? SO meant to be one question per post, and these multipart questions are harder to answer. I don't work with PHP much, so I can only point you to [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP). Without more info, like an actual error message, I don't think we can do much else.

Answer (score 0):

With `shell_exe` or `exec` use:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i Temp.mp3 -af loudnorm=I=-12:LRA=7:tp=-2:measured_I=-30:measured_LRA=1.1:measured_tp=-11 04:measured_thresh=-40.21:offset=-0.47 -y output.mp 2>&1');
```

`2 refers to the second file descriptor of the process, i.e. stderr.`

`> means redirection.`

`&1 means the target of the redirection should be the same location as the first file descriptor, i.e. stdout.`

In `$output` you will have the response. If the apache user `www-data` doesn't have enough rights execute the comand as `sudo`

Comment: No output. Not any normalized file generated, not any value on "$output", no errors :-/